# How to implement Caesar Cipher encryption / decryption in javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, caesar-cipher

First post so I hope I am not making a fool of my self.

I have a project due at University its a basic JavaScript string encryption and decryption funciton.

Key problem I was off on the day we went through the basics of the encryptor, due to a hospital appointment.

I am not looking for the whole answer, just a good base to start from as I have left this rather last minute.

The assignment basically wants me to implement, on a website I have already made, a string encrytor whereby it will move the characters along a certain number of places i.e. for 3 places A would be D, then another option to reverse it, which once I have the initial code the second bit would be easy.

It should form part of the website so there would be a box in the site that I type the string in and would click a button to encrypt/decrypt.

I have only used a few basic JavaScript functions so my understanding is not great but I am a quick learner if I have something to work with

Comment: Just to be clear, is this what you are trying to do ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher

Comment: Looks too broad to me. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @PraveenKumar too broad but I think we can provide some useful hints but putting a name on what he has to do. I don't think he has to implement something new

Comment: Google found this: http://jsfiddle.net/tC7qe/19/